# How to get specific value from relation table in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

There are 4 tables (teacher, instrument, day, hour) which have many to many relation. The problem is:  Two teachers instruct the same instrument at different hours of the day. I specified the time of instruction for each of them at different hours. But When I retrieve the instruction time of one teacher, the other's time of instruction is also shown. How can I solve this problem?

teacher's model :

```
public function instruments(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Instrument::class);
}

public function times(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Time::class);
}

public function days(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Day::class);
}
```

instrument's model

```
public function teachers(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Teacher::class);
}

public function times(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Time::class);
}

public function days(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Day::class);
}
```

day's model

```
public function teachers(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Teacher::class);
}

public function times(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Time::class);
}

public function instruments(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Instrument::class);
}
```

time's model

```
public function teachers(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Teacher::class);
}

public function days(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Day::class);
}

public function instruments(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Instrument::class);
}




teachers table 

id      name 
1       john 
2       mike


 days table

id      name 
1       sat 
2       sun
3       mon

times table

id      name 
1       11:00 
2       11:30
3       12:00

day_teacher table

day_id      teacher_id 
  1            1 
  1            2 
  
day_time table

day_id      time_id 
  1            1 
  1            2 

  teacher_time table

teacher_id      time_id 
   1               1 
   2               1
   2               2
```

Retrieve time's teacher in teacherController with teacher id and day id with route model binding

```
public function gettime(Teacher $teacher, Day $day)
{
    $res1 = $teacher->times()->pluck('id');
    $res2 = $day->times()->pluck('id');
   Time::whereIn('id', $res1)->whereIn('id', $res2)->get();
}
```

How can I set 11:00 for first teacher and 11:30 for second

It shows 11:00 & 11:30 for first teacher

Comment: That's because you are telling it to do so. Right now, your `gettime` function is returning the teacher model with all the times for each days of this teacher. A better way to do this would be to put your `gettime()` function directly in the `Teacher.php` model and maybe take a `day` as argument so you can return a specific time for this teacher at that day.

Comment: I know it , but my point is time value that i set for this teacher is for example 11:00 for sunday and when i eager load all times for this teacher it shows me 11:00 & 11:30 on sunday ( 11:30 is time that i set for second teacher on sunday )

Comment: I think you have to use `morph`, as `days` do not have a `teacher` ID association, `day` only associates to `Teacher` but not `Time`... So if you want a `day`, then `time` is the same, as you are not telling for which `Teacher` it is.